# Закрывать бургер-меню нажимая вне его области

Tags: javascript, html, css

Когда открывается бургер меню, его можно закрыть пока что двумя способами, это нажать или на крестик, или на одну из ссылок навигации. Но не понимаю как сделать так, чтоб он закрывался при нажатии вне его области.

Код

```
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const menuItems = document.querySelector(".menu-items");
const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");
const menuScreen = document.querySelector(".overlay");


function toggle() {
    menuBtn.classList.toggle("open");
    menuItems.classList.toggle("open");
    menuScreen.classList.toggle("open");
}

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    toggle();
})


menuItem.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if(menuBtn.classList.contains("open")) {
            toggle();
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос.

```
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const menuItems = document.querySelector(".menu-items");
const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");
const menuScreen = document.querySelector(".overlay");


function toggle() {
    menuBtn.classList.toggle("open");
    menuItems.classList.toggle("open");
    menuScreen.classList.toggle("open");
}

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    
    toggle();
})


menuItem.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if(menuBtn.classList.contains("open")) {
            toggle();
        } 
    });

    document.addEventListener('click', e => {
        let target = e.target,
        its_menu = target == menuItems || menuItems.contains(target),
        its_hamburger = target == menuBtn,
        menu_is_active = menuItems.classList.contains('open');
        
        if (!its_menu && !its_hamburger && menu_is_active) {
          toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Я решил создать навигационное меню, которое при раскрытии вешает обработчик событий на родительский элемент `main` (закрытие фиксированного меню) и свои дочерние элементы (закрытие фиксированного меню, в примере только `ul`).

Отодвигаю родительский элемент на 200px (высота меню), чтобы избежать клика по нему и было видно содержимое, иначе его перекрывает фиксированное меню

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  let nav = document.querySelector("#nav"),
  burger = document.querySelector("#clickable"),
  close = document.querySelector("#close"),
  main = document.querySelector("#main");

  function changeBack(){
    if ( event.target !== nav ){
      nav.style.opacity = "0";
      nav.style.display = "none";
      main.classList.remove('m200');
      burger.style.display = "flex";
    }
  }


  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
     document.querySelector('#main').classList.add("m200");
     nav.style.display = "block";
     setTimeout(() => nav.style.opacity = "1", 50);
     burger.style.display = "none";
     main.addEventListener("click", changeBack, false);
    
  });

  nav.addEventListener("click", changeBack, false);
  
  close.addEventListener("click", changeBack, false);


});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.m200{
  padding-top: 200px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main p {
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  font-family: monospace;
  max-width: 800px;
}


#clickable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 10px 5px 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#clickable span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #39f;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}

#clickable:hover span::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

#clickable:hover span::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 5px 16px 0px #0B325E, 2px 4px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0); 
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 16px 0px #0B325E, 2px 4px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #39f;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

#close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 94px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="clickable">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<main id="main">
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="link">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="link">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="link">3</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div id="close">&times;</div>
</nav>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</main>
```